# Heroku Application Error - app will not deploy

Tags: ajax, heroku, github

I am looking to deploy my simple web application to Heroku. The build process has come back as successful, however, once I click to open the app I am getting an application error. I have pasted the log error below. I understand that it's probably something to do with NPM, but I can't decipher exactly what it's trying to tell me to do.

It is linked to the GitHub repo below.

https://github.com/KUBIX90/random-quote-machine

Thanks for your help,

```
2017-09-14T19:21:54.769808+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2017-09-14T19:21:54.782902+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-09-14T19:21:54.765726+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
2017-09-14T19:21:54.765371+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v6.11.3
2017-09-14T19:21:54.764745+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic
2017-09-14T19:21:54.783256+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-09-14T19:21:54.769914+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2017-09-14T19:21:54.769466+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2017-09-14T19:21:56.053971+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=random-quote-generator-kubix90.herokuapp.com request_id=2ad5343c-8fec-405c-9def-8fbb01a09a00 fwd="31.54.253.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-14T19:23:36.975442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=random-quote-generator-kubix90.herokuapp.com request_id=63ae20ae-4189-4693-b08e-f2e17615ab5d fwd="31.54.253.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-14T19:23:43.812544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=random-quote-generator-kubix90.herokuapp.com request_id=a6c4a51a-01ca-49a7-860d-4ea1014b10dc fwd="31.54.253.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-14T19:25:11.887291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=random-quote-generator-kubix90.herokuapp.com request_id=b7f15816-8a6e-484b-abc0-147cc63df0f1 fwd="31.54.253.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-14T19:30:28.059667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=random-quote-generator-kubix90.herokuapp.com request_id=7ed95d5e-92dd-4afb-83fe-59479d6c070f fwd="31.54.253.151" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Update -- I've added the following to the package JSON, but I am still getting an error

`"scripts": {
       "start": "node your-script.js"},`

Comment: `npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/random-quote-machine
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'random-quote-machine' is not in the npm registry.`